# Apply Formula automatically in Feyncalc

Tags: feyncalc

I want to apply the function Tdec in Feyncalc automatically. Here is an example what the input is:

```
(GAD[x].FVD[k, x] + \[Omega]*
      GAD[x].FVD[v, x]).(GAD[y].FVD[k, y] + \[Omega]*
      GAD[y].FVD[v, y]) // ExpandScalarProduct // DiracSimplify
```

Output:

```
\[Omega]*DiracGamma[Momentum[k, D], D] . 
   DiracGamma[Momentum[v, D], D] + 
 \[Omega]*DiracGamma[Momentum[v, D], D] . 
   DiracGamma[Momentum[k, D], D] + 
 Pair[Momentum[k, D], Momentum[k, D]] + 
 \[Omega]^2*Pair[Momentum[v, D], Momentum[v, D]]
```

So now i want to apply the function on Tdec which takes the form of:

```
\[Omega]*GAD[x].Tdec[{k, x}, {v}, List -> False].GAD[y].FVD[v, 
    y] + \[Omega]*
  GAD[y].FVD[v, y].Tdec[{k, x}, {v}, List -> False].GAD[x] + SPD[k,k] + 
 SPD[v,v]*\[Omega]^2
```

Is there any way of applying Tdec automatically to the first equation to obtain the last equation which was done by hand?

Comment: Try TID (https://www.feyncalc.org/FeynCalcBook/TID/index.html)

Comment: I dont have a denominator, therefore i cannot use TID right? The examples are all based on FAD[..]

Comment: It should be easy to write something similar to [this](https://github.com/FeynCalc/feynonium/blob/master/NRQCD/FMCartesianTensorDecomposition.m). You essentially need only Uncontract and FCLoopIsolate.